# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am new to selenium.

In below code `firefox` is being launched but i am unable to make any entry in the textbox.

```
package webdrivers;

import java.sql.Driver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.SendKeys;

public class Automation 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
       driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("your_username");   
    }
}
```

Error is:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800' System info: host: 'RAHUL', ip: '192.168.1.109', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.cduJLZVQoFth, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=6.3, moz:processID=6184, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}] Session ID: 452dde13-0981-4d4d-bb9a-beb6739485d5
```

Comment: You probably need By.id("email"), I guess the WebElement returned by driver.findElement(By.name("email")) is undefined

Comment: It's not working with id also. Throwing the same error.

Comment: I think both ways should work, I guess Dev's answer (Gecko driver) will fix your problem.

Comment: @bert I agree, both should work but I always try to provide the minimal tweak needed in OP's code to make his/her code work :)

Answer (score 2):

To work with Selenium 3.4.0 you need to download gecko driver v0.16.0 or higher from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and save it. Upgrade your Mozila Firefox to 53.x

Next you need to provide the absolute path of the gecko driver in your code. Your code will look like:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",  "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("your_username");
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: 1493291531075 addons.manager ERROR startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70"  data: no] StackJ traavcaeS:c rFiiplte Uetrirlosr_:g erteDsioru(r)c@er:e/s/ogurrec/em:o/d/greu/modluelse/sA/dFdiolneMUatnialgse.rj.sjms:m7,0  l<i Fniel e1U6t5i7l:s _NgSe_tEFRiRlOeR(_)N@OrTe_sIoNuIrTcIeA:L/I/ZgErDe:/ mAddoondMualneasg/eFri liesU tniolts i.njistmi:a4l2i z<e dv
a

Now a different error.

Comment: Thats because you have several addons in your Mozilla Firefox profile. You have 2 options, The easier one is to delete the add-ons and retest. Else you have to create a new Firefox profile.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way..Download gecko_driver from this [link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

**Note:-** If your dealing with latest `gecko driver version`(v0.16.0), make sure your `firefox` browser is updated to latest version(V53).

Update selenium jar files as well as. you can download selenium latest jar files from this [link](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");   // Your gecko_driver path.
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("Username");
```

Comment: 1493291531075 addons.manager ERROR startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70"  data: no] StackJ traavcaeS:c rFiiplte Uetrirlosr_:g erteDsioru(r)c@er:e/s/ogurrec/em:o/d/greu/modluelse/sA/dFdiolneMUatnialgse.rj.sjms:m7,0  l<i Fniel e1U6t5i7l:s _NgSe_tEFRiRlOeR(_)N@OrTe_sIoNuIrTcIeA:L/I/ZgErDe:/ mAddoondMualneasg/eFri liesU tniolts i.njistmi:a4l2i z<e dv
a



A different error.

Comment: Have you replace a `gecko_driver` path properly?

Comment: package webdrivers;
public class Automation {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\gecko driver\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
  driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("your_username");   
   }
}


Yaa i did but not working..!!

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("Username");`

Comment: Update above line of code from your script and then check. your firefox browser version? have you installed latest selenium jar files (3.4.0)?

Answer (score 1):

This is an ongoing issue with geckodriver:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/659

If you still want to work with firefox : you can downgrade firefox to v52 and then along with geckodriver v0.15 you'll be able to work fine.